# Rendering image with webapi and E-tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How to use the caching with resource like Image tag in HTML which will be rendered via Web api and i would like to use the E-tag caching for doing it.

How to do the E-tag caching on the IMG tag from Html  .

Comment: You can't do this from HTML. You will need to tell the server to send the right headers

Comment: Ya if i send a right header from WEB api . how can the IMG tag checks with correct GUID. will it store internally

Answer (score 0):

Rendered HTML is a **composed resource** as such is not a good candidate for caching. For example, even if you have a current datetime on the HTML, it would be unsuitable for caching. Also some resources have user-specific requirements and the task of managing these caches is a real pain.

For simple resources you can use [CacheCow](https://github.com/aliostad/CacheCow). This library is in development, v0.1 already released on NuGet. More on it [here](http://byterot.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/introducing-cachecow-http-caching.html).

Comment: But i think we can cache only the image tag or image in the local browser so that image does'nt need to reterieved again

Comment: You can cache any response as specified in HTTP spec: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.4